# filter customer by attributes

Tags: magento-1, customer, filter

I want to show customer having specific value for attribute.
Suppose I made customer attribute say refcode, now I want to get list of all customer having refcode 1.

How can I add filter to list of customer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `refcode` is `customer   eav` then you can filter this by function `addAttributeFilter('attributecode','fiterablevalue')`

1St: Need to load customer collection

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
```

2nd: then filter by addAttributeToFilter()

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('refcode',1)
```

3rd: `foreach` loop to get  get list of all customer having refcode 1.

For add `an eav attribute` to collection you need to use the function `addAttributeToSelect('attribute_code')`

add

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('refcode');
```

**For getting all field** use -`>addAttributeToSelect('*')` function w`hich is include all eav attribute` to collection

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

If you want `a collection to array` then use below function `->__toArray ()` or `->toArray()`

That means to get array of collection use below as exmpale

```
$collection->toArray();
```

Comment: wrote below code:
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('refcode',1);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($collection);
echo '</pre>';

but could not find any customer data like email or else ??

Comment: then?.....................

Comment: could not get list of customer with above condition , it get large array as ouput i search but there was no email and customer name in whole  array

Comment: i wrote below code :$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('refcode')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('refcode',1);
   
   print_r($collection);

still not able to get email

Answer (score 3):

You can get collection of customer through :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
```

Filter you collection according to attribute :

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('refcode', array('eq' => 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add the attribute to the grid, using:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl

Then you can filter the grid by the attribute

Comment: i want customer having value of attribute like email 'abc@c.om'