# addFieldToFilter in customer collection

Tags: customer, collection

I would like to add filters (with addFieldToFilter or other) in my customer collection `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')`.

In sql it is:

```
WHERE (billing_country_id = "FR" AND (billing_telephone LIKE "06%" 
OR billing_telephone LIKE "07%")) OR billing_telephone LIKE "00%" 
OR billing_telephone LIKE "+%"
```

I have created:

```
(billing_country_id = "FR" AND (billing_telephone LIKE "06%" 
OR billing_telephone LIKE "07%") ",
```

but i don't know how add:

```
 " OR billing_telephone LIKE "00%" OR billing_telephone LIKE "+%" ".
```

This is the beginning :

```
 ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute' => 'billing_country_id', 'eq' => "FR")
        )
    )
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute' => 'billing_telephone', 'like' => "06%"),
            array('attribute' => 'billing_telephone', 'like' => "07%")
        )
    )
```

Comment: please that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42500/filter-customer-by-attributes/42505#42505

Answer (score 0):

you need add address table on your customer  collection

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```